# Titanium - Strange transition from splash screen on SDK 5.2.0

Tags: appcelerator, appcelerator-titanium

My app has a splash image the is the same as the background image of the first screen of the app. So when starting the app, the transition from the splash screen to the app is smooth - you see the splash and the just buttons that appear - you don't see the background moving, or changing not even in one pixel.

I've started writing my app with sdk 5.1.2 - and that worked great for me.

I've upgraded my app to use the new 5.2.0 SDK (still using regular splash and **not** the storyboard). In the new SDK the splash shows, then fades out, then you see a black screen, then you see the main page of the app appear. Far from being the smooth transition of 5.1.2.

If I go back to older SDK version - I don't have the problem - but I don't want to get stuck behind in SDK versions - I want to be able to enjoy new features and bug fixes.

Anyone know if it's something that was changed on purpose? or if there is some workaround?

Comment: Could you provide a test app? I just upgraded a personal app from 5.1.2.GA to 5.2.0.GA and I see no difference.

Comment: now I'm facing another strange behaviour - after going back to 5.2.0 I don't have my splash any more - just storyboard splash. setting `enable-launch-screen-storyboard` to false doesn't help.

Comment: You say "after going back to 5.2.0", but didn't you go from 5.1.2 to 5.2.0? Could you please provide exact steps, because it sure looks like something odd is going on. Please create a JIRA ticket so we can discuss it there since it definitely looks like its heading to a bug ;)

Comment: sure. will create one. after removing the app and reinstalling it than I see my splash back - not the storyboard image. and the fade is faster - so now it just looks like fast flickering. will try to reproduce in side project.

Comment: It's really weird because looking at the source at https://github.com/appcelerator/titanium_mobile/blob/1a4d814dffb007bb9eda47687ceb4f8d5b066590/iphone/cli/commands/_build.js#L2109 it looks like unless you have the flag in tiapp.xml it will disable storyboards

Comment: @Fokke-Appcelerator I was able to reproduce the problem with a new project. Added comment to JIRA.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug and we have a FIX pending review:
https://jira.appcelerator.org/browse/TIMOB-20453

Comment: will be released in next sdk version?

Comment: Yes, it will be in 5.2.1 to be released late March

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue.  I added the following to the tiapp.xml:

```
<ios>
    <default-background-color>#ffffff</default-background-color>
```

.
.
.

You still get a blank screen before the app starts up but at least the screen is solid white which matches my theme better than the black screen.

Comment: That helps, but if this is a valid we as Appcelerator need to get it fixed asap.